# meaning of "fallen little short of a mother in affection" in Jane Austen's Emma, Chapter I

Tags: meaning, phrases

> She was the youngest of the two daughters of a most affectionate, indulgent father; ad had, in consequence of her sister's marriage, been mistress of his house from a very early peroid. Her mother had died too long ago for her to have more than an indistinct remembrance of her caresses; and her place had been supplied by an excellent woman as governess, who had fallen little short of a mother in affection.

At the end of this paragraph, I am not sure about the meaning of " fallen little short of mother in affection". The meaning of fall short (of) is being inadequate, but as I read some translation in my native language, it has been translated as she being a very good mother. How can I understand this sentence exactly?

Answer (score 8):

The meaning of **fall short** is more like **not quite reaching.** For example, if you throw a ball and it **falls short** then it doesn't go as far as you intended to throw it, it does not reach its target.

From this you can see that **fall short** *might* have a negative meaning if someone's behaviour **falls short** of what is expected of them.

However, in your quotation the expression is qualified by **little**. Austen means that the governess had fallen short of being a real mother by such a small amount that she had been almost as good as a real mother

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

But it doesn't say "had fallen short". It says "had fallen [*little*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/little) short":

> small in amount or number

It's a litotes.